# How to show each row as different page in SSRS reports?

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer

How can I show each ROW of a Select Query in Different page in SSRS Reports. ie If I have 20 rows it should be shown in 20 different pages.

Is it possible? I tried many ways but none is working. All the 20 rows will be displayed in the same page as a table. I don't want to show it in the same page instead each row should be displayed in each page.

Answer (score 2):

This should help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156434(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: I checked and PageBreak Properties isn't exist for row. This is possible only for tablix.

Answer (score 1):

This approach may work. Basically you can create a group (with no group header, detail, or footer row visible) with a group expression for each 1 row, and set the page break properties at the group level.

http://sqlserverrider.wordpress.com/2011/06/20/page-break-at-nth-row-in-ssrs-report/